# GenerateAppearances = true; System.NullReferenceException

Tags: itext, pdfstamper

Got some legacy code using iTextSharp.

All documents have GenerateAppearances set to true regardless. and now its triggering an exception.

Took the basic code out and placed it into a Console app, same thing, Used a generic PDF (http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) of the net same thing.

This is using version 5.5.12

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\pdf.pdf"); 

        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);

        stamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true; <--- usually true before setting
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    }
}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in itextsharp.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks

Comment: Define legacy code. Are you talking about an iTextSharp version that is several years old? In that case, the question risks to be closed for the following reason: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced."

Comment: This example happens with the latest version - 5.5.12.

Comment: OK, in that case it surprises me that you have to set `GenerateAppearances` to `true`. Have you checked if `stamper.AcroFields` is not `null`? It is normal that you get a `NullReferenceException` in case you process a document that isn't an AcroForm (it may look like a form to the human eye, but that doesn't mean it's a form to a machine).

Comment: AcroFields is not null. GenerateAppearances is true all before assigning true again. Triggers an exception:

System.NullReferenceException.Data: ListDictionaryInternal Count is 0

Answer (score 1):

After years of production, I just changed it from:

```
if (stamper.AcroFields != null)
{
    f.GenerateAppearances = true;

    foreach(var field in f.Fields)
    {
        f.SetField(field.Key, f.GetField(field.Key));
    }

    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
}
```

to

```
if (stamper.AcroFields != null && stamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances == true)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the change, but I'm glad to see that you were able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issues as below:
When I set AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true
an unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in itextsharp.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I debugged this code and found that AcroFields is not null. but NullReferenceException still occourred.

After inverstigating, I found that the format of PDF file is aspose xfa rather than acroforms. **So I solved this issue by converting the format of PDF from aspose xfa to acroforms.**

Comment: What do you mean by "*aspose* xfa"? XFA is a semi-proprietary *Adobe* format...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).